# XPATH select condition with the latest date

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have the following XML:

```
<STATUSLIST>
    <STATUS>
        <TYPE VALUE="1"/>
        <DATE>19910000</DATE>
    </STATUS>
    <STATUS>
        <TYPE VALUE="1"/>
        <DATE>19470000</DATE>
    </STATUS>
    <STATUS>
        <TYPE VALUE="2"/>
        <DATE>19470000</DATE>
    </STATUS>
</STATUSLIST>
```

And I would like to match the `STATUS` where `TYPE/@VALUE = '2'` and `not(//STATUSLIST/STATUS/DATE > DATE)`.
In this case it would be the 3rd `STATUS`.

When I apply the type with the latest date I get nothing because it can't match both. What I would like is to match the `TYPE/@VALUE = '2'` first and in that match get the one with the latest date.

Any clue?

Cheers,

Tuno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution: `STATUS[TYPE/@VALUE = '2'][not(//STATUSLIST/STATUS[TYPE/@VALUE = '2']/DATE > DATE)]`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want correctly, you cannot do this all in XPath v1 due to the lack of a maximum function. So get all the `STATUS` elements with the desired TYPE:

```
/STATUSLIST/STATUS[TYPE/@VALUE=2]
```

and then sort or maximum function in the calling environment.

Comment: What I am looking is first TYPE/@VALUE=2 and then latest date of that result. This will AND with no results.

Comment: @Tuno XPath expression was left over from by first pass over an answer, before a re-read of the Q made it clear you were looking for a maximum (which XPath 1 doesn't support—any the question doesn't specify the XPath version so I assumed lowest common denominator).

Answer (score 0):

While your own solution of `STATUS[TYPE/@VALUE = '2'][not(//STATUSLIST/STATUS[TYPE/@VALUE = '2']/DATE > DATE)]` will work, it is not particularly efficient for large numbers of entries as you're comparing every `STATUS` with every other `STATUS`, so O(N<sup>2</sup>).  More efficient would be to implement it as a tail-recursive function (as you say you're using XSLT 2.0) such as the following:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
                xmlns:local="urn:local" exclude-result-prefixes="local">

  <xsl:function name="local:latestByDate" as="item()*">
    <xsl:param name="seq" as="item()*"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="local:latestByDate($seq, ())" />
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:function name="local:latestByDate" as="item()*">
    <xsl:param name="seq" as="item()*" />
    <xsl:param name="maxSoFar" as="item()*" />
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$seq">
        <!-- calculate the new maxSoFar, comparing the current max with
             the first item in $seq.  Note the use of not(x<=y) instead of
             x>y, so the test is true if $maxSoFar is the empty sequence -->
        <xsl:variable name="newMax"
                      select="if(not($seq[1]/DATE &lt;= $maxSoFar/DATE))
                              then $seq[1] else $maxSoFar"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="local:latestByDate(
                                 $seq[position() gt 1], $newMax)" />
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <!-- we have reached the end of $seq, return the max -->
        <xsl:sequence select="$maxSoFar" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:function>

  <!-- example of how to call the function -->
  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy-of select="local:latestByDate(STATUS[TYPE/@VALUE='2'])" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This function makes a single pass over the list of nodes (so O(N)), keeping track at each step of which element in the input sequence has the latest `DATE`.

Comment: Hi Ian, thanks for the reply. We don't have large numbers of entries. So for our case the simple and slower solutions is sufficient. I hope that XSLT will incorporate this in a easier way.